# Laravel 8 - The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, delete-row, laravel-8

I am trying to delete a record from DataTable by submitting a form through clicking the input submit button but this error always shows:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.

This is my current declared route in **`web.php`** into:

```
Route::delete('sales/deleteSalesOrder/{id}', 'Transaction\SaleController@deleteSalesOrder')->name('sales/deleteSalesOrder/{id}')->middleware('role:A');
```

This is my snippet code for creating the form inside the **`DataTable`**:

```
public function dataTableTrash()
{
    $data = SalesH::where('active', '=', 2);
    
    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addColumn('action', function($data){

        $url = url('transaction/sales/'.$data->id);
        $undoTrash = url('sales/undoTrash/'.$data->id);
        $urlDestroy = url('sales/deleteSalesOrder/'.$data->id);

        $view = "<a class = 'btn btn-primary' href = '".$url."' title = 'View'><i class = 'nav icon fas fa-eye'></i></a>";
        $undo = "<button data-url = '".$undoTrash."' onclick = 'undoTrash(this)' class = 'btn btn-action btn-success' title = 'Re-Activate'><i class='fas fa-trash-restore-alt'></i></button>";
        $delete = "<form action='$urlDestroy' class = 'deleteForm' method='post'>
                        <div class='form-group'>
                            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger delete-user' value='Delete'>
                        </div>
                    </form>";
                    
        return $view."".$undo."".$delete;

    })->editColumn('date', function($data){
        return date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->date));
    })->editColumn('total', function($data){
        return number_format($data->total, 0, '.', ',');
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action'])
    ->make(true);
}
```

As you notice the form does not have yet the **`csrf_field()`** and **`method_field('DELETE')`**. what I did is I just added it using JQuery in the blade file.

```
@push('js')

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.deleteForm').submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     console.log('LOL I am working!');
     $(this).append('{{ csrf_field() }}');
     $(this).append('{{ method_field('DELETE') }}');
     if (confirm('Are you sure you want to PERMANENTLY delete this data?')) {
        event.currentTarget.submit();
     });
   }
</script>
@endpush
```

And finally my **`deleteSalesOrder()`** (method for deleting the data):

```
public function deleteSalesOrder($id)
{
     $data = SalesH::find($id);
     $data->delete();

     if($data->save()){
         Toastr::success('Sales Order has been permanently deleted.', 'Success');
         return view('Transaction.Sales.index');
     }else{
         Toastr::error('Sales Order failed to be deleted.', 'Error');
         return view('Transaction.Sales.index');
     }
}
```

What causes this error? Is it right to just append the **`csrf_field()`** and **`method_field('DELETE')`** using JQuery? And how do I fix the problem and Successfully delete the data in this case?

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is you are appending to a form named `deleteForm` which does not exist. no name attribute in your from rather it's an id attribute. and every form has the same id which won't work as in a dom there should be only one element with an id. better use a class attribute and when submitting the form add those csrf and method field to that form rather in document ready.
the form

```
<form action='$urlDestroy' class='deleteForm' method='post'>
```

and then in script

```
$('.deleteForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).append('{{ csrf_field() }}');
    $(this).append('{{ method_field('DELETE') }}');
    // write confirm code if you want
    event.currentTarget.submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the deleteForm. I tried your solution but it when I click the delete button it says `Page Expired`. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: it means the `event.preventDefault()` is not working. make sure you have added the class and and try to add this code block inside document ready function.

Comment: Followed your instructions. also added your snipper code solution inside the ready function but still the `Page Expired`

Comment: comment out rest of the code after preventDefault and just after preventDefault add a console log..check if the function actually hitting

Comment: console log does not print anything and it immediately goes to the `Page Expired`

Comment: it means the function is not hitting. do you add the class name `deleteForm` in the form??

Comment: yes i added it `<form action='$urlDestroy' class = 'deleteForm' method='post'>`

Comment: give an id to your table and try with `$('#dataTable').on('click', 'deleteForm', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           console.log('ok');
});` where table id is `dataTable`